# PHP 7 strtotime() timezone calculation

Tags: php, datetime, php-7

We just migrated from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 and we ran into an issue with the `strtotime()` method

The applications calculates the localtime from a UTC time to do this we used the following code

```
$timezone = " UTC+0100";
$localTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now".$timezone));
```

which would output the local time

So i tested it locally

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now UTC+0100"));
?>
```

And the result in PHP 5.6 is

`2017-01-20 09:13:49
2017-01-20 10:13:49`

And the result in PHP 7 is

`2017-01-20 09:13:49
2017-01-20 09:13:49`

Is there some thing I'm doing wrong or did something change in the syntax for PHP 7?

I know the best way is could do this is to use the DateTime class from PHP and i will implement it in the long term but for now i'm looking for a quick solution

Comment: `2017-01-20 10:36:28 
2017-01-20 11:36:28` I am using PHP 7. I get your expected result. seems nothing problem with PHP 7

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php Look at changelog nothing changed after PHP 5.3

Comment: This is probably not a PHP issue but rather somewhere along the line you've set a different default timezone.  Check https://eval.in/720683 and https://eval.in/720684

Comment: strtotime calls gettimeofday if im right?

Comment: `strtotime("now UTC+0100"))` - that seems like a bogus approach to begin with. You are _not_ calculating a “local time” here. The unix timestamp is the same all over the world, no matter what timezone you are in. The timezone comes into play when you _format_ a unix timestamp in a human-readable format.

Comment: @apokryfos you are right so i've set the local timezone and the time is translated to the localtime i only need to provide the UTC in the date so this works now ```echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2017-01-20 10:13:00 UTC"));```

Comment: @CBroe i know this was just for testing. i was trying to see if the UTC time would be converted to my local time. in the application itself a date is provided like this  ```strtotime($utcdatetime." UTC+0100"))``` so that the timestamp provided to ```date()``` was the local timestamp. i know it isn't the best approach but it was the best i could come up with 3 years ago